# Why swift cannot find my Objective-C class in ProductModule-Swift.h

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have this code a Custom class which extends `UIImageView` in Objective-C.

When I add to the project and add import to bridging header file my swift class can see
and use the code as usual but when i try to compile it.

I always get this error

[image]

I don't know why it is only happen to my `CarBigImageView`, I try to change the name of the file , create new file with new name and copy all the code there but none seem to work.

but other custom view such as Marker seem to be fine?

**UPDATE : ADD MORE INFORMATION**

here is my bridging header

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
#import <AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h>
#import <GSKeychain.h>
#import <JSONKit.h>

#import "CarBigImageView.h"
#import "sqlite3.h"
#import <time.h>
#import "Bridge.h"
#import "Marker.h"
```

here is my "CarBigImageView.h"

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol CarBigImageViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didTouchColor:(UIColor*)coloc atPosition:(CGPoint)point;

@end

@interface CarBigImageView : UIImageView

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<CarBigImageViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

and here what it looks in the editor

[image]

and the result when compile

[image]

How can i solve this?

Comment: Are you able to show your code in bridging header file? If you think you are doing correctly, how about closing the entire project and then reopen it? It could be due to the slowness of indexing.

Comment: Where is `CarBigImageViewDelegate` declared?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. Please make an effort to actually type in the code and errors.

Comment: I have done that for a reason. I want to provide as much information as i can and how can i type the code with correct colour as in Xcode?

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you left Xcode know where to find that file: in build settings look for "Objective-C Bridging Header". The value for that field should be something similar to "$(SRCROOT)/path/to/your/Bridging-Header.h" If you fill this out and hit enter, it SRCROOT will expand, and you can check if that full path is correct path.